# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, discord py

Tags: python, discord

song_names = ['Masked Wolf - Astronaut in the Ocean', 'Billie Eilish - bad guy']

````
async def queue(ctx):
    counter = 1
    print(song_names)
    for str in song_names:
        await ctx.channel.send(counter + song_names[str])
        counter += 1```

This is the error I get:

```  File "E:/.MAIN/Files/Programming/Main/main.py", line 430, in queue
    await ctx.channel.send(counter + song_names[str])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already iterating over the items sp you can just use the variable and don't use `str` as variable name:

```
async def queue(ctx):
    counter = 1
    print(song_names)
    for mystr in song_names:
        await ctx.channel.send(str(counter) + mystr)
        counter += 1
```

And its looking like you need `enumerate()`:

```
async def queue(ctx):
    print(song_names)
    for index, mystr in enumerate(song_names):
        await ctx.channel.send(str(index+1) + mystr)
```

Answer (score 1):

When looping a list, it normally iterates through each element. In your case, you want to get the index of the current iterating element. For that, You can use `enumerate` in Python:

**Syntax:**

```
enumerate(iterable, start=0)
```

Full code:

```
async def queue(ctx):
    counter = 1
    print(song_names)
    for index, song_name in enumerate(song_names):
        await ctx.channel.send(counter + song_names[index])
        counter += 1
```